# Payara : High memory utilization of "admin-cli" - parent process

Tags: glassfish, payara

We have a single machine in which multiple local payara instances are running through the windows services , those services are created using usual "create-service" asadmin command.

The problem which we are facing recently is that the parent process which started the payara local instance started consuming more memory ( ~1 to1.5 GB ).

We understand that this parent process triggered using the below command is just to start the "local-instance" and to monitor it,  so the memory consumption should be under <200MB ( startup consumption) and should not reach till ~ >= 1GB.

```
nadmin.bat start-local-instance --watchdog --nodedir D:/payara5/glassfish/nodes --node localhost-production <localInstanceName>
```

As we have not much control on this parent process (admin-cli) memory consumption we tried to find other options in the documentation to start all instances using a single window service but I believe there is no such option available.

The deployment group is something that can be used but there is no way to create a windows service for the deployment group ( pls correct me if I'm wrong ).

Please suggest what could be the issue for this high memory utilization of this parent process(admin-cli) to start the instance in --watchdog mode.

We tried taking the heap dump of this parent process as well but the heap size is not reflecting the actual memory consumption. For example : actual process is taking 1 GB but the heap size is showing <50MB.

Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance.
Abdul Mohsin

Answer (score 1):

We also had problems once with a similar issue where the `asadmin` command would take up too much memory.

The reason for this is that the process has no heap size limit set and hence takes up a certain portion of memory when starting up (usually 1/4th). This depends on different parameters like your OS, RAM size or processor architecture. See [Server JVM initial and maximum heap sizes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#sthref31)

However, since we did not want to change anything of the Payara-provided scripts we got around the problem by setting `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xmx128m` in the shell environment where we called the `asadmin` process. That forced a heap size of 128MB for the `asadmin` process.

If you want to directly change the batch file then you might as well write

```
%JAVA% -Xmx128m -jar "%~dp0..\modules\admin-cli.jar" %*
```

Comment: Thanks Christoph !   
Just wanted to confirm have you added it on the batch file : "nadmin.bat" on below command : 
`%JAVA% -jar "%~dp0..\modules\admin-cli.jar" %*`

Regards,
Abdul